# Paypal express payment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

Does anyone can give any sample on using the paypal express payment feature with asp.net mvc2?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find sample code here, [PayPal integration sample code](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but for anyone else looking for an express checkout implementation using ASP.NET MVC and wants sample code that isn't Java or PHP (eg C#) you can use this;
https://bitbucket.org/jhelmink/paypalexpresscheckoutmvc

Disclaimer: I wrote it.